# If $f\in L^1$ has a compact support and $0 \leq p \leq1$ then $|f|^p\in L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

My text proved that

> If $f\in L^1$ is bounded and $p \geq1$ then $|f|^p\in L^1$

I wanted to prove the seemingly very similar statement:

> If $f\in L^1$ has a compact support and $0 \leq p \leq1$ then $|f|^p\in L^1$

I was able to mimic the proof from the text yet I guess one can use the first statement to prove the second. Any idea how?

Comment: What is assumed about the underlying measure space?

Comment: I am very unsure about this suggestion, since I partially forgot the exact statements of the theorems: Perhaps you can approximate the function $f$ by a continuous function with a compact support. The continuous function will be bounded by the extreme value theorem ... Perhaps this would be a way of using the first statement

Comment: @triple_sec: it's just the $\mathbb R^n$ with Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @LeoSchmidt Then I think there is a way to make use of my suggestion. I am unable to write a proof because I forgot the theorems. But I "feel" that my intuition can be made rigorous, using Lusin's theorem

Comment: @Amr: you are right, this is how my text proves the 1st statement, and how I mimicked it to prove the 2nd. Yet my question is about a quick argument to follow the 2nd from the 1st.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
\begin{align*}
A\equiv&\,\{x\in \mathbb R^n\,|\,0<|f(x)|\leq 1\},\\
B\equiv&\,\{x\in \mathbb R^n\,|\,|f(x)|> 1\}.
\end{align*}
Note that both sets are contained in the support of $f$ and since $f$ is compactly supported, it follows that $A$ and $B$ are bounded sets. In particular, $m(A)<\infty$ and $m(B)<\infty$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$.

Now, let $p\in[0,1]$. Then,
\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb R^n}|f(x)|^p\,\mathrm d x=&\,\int_A|f(x)|^p\,\mathrm d x+\int_B|f(x)|^p\,\mathrm d x\\
\leq&\,\int_A|f(x)|^p\,\mathrm d x+\int_{B}|f(x)|\,\mathrm d x\\
\leq&\,\int_A|f(x)|^p\,\mathrm d x+\int_{\mathbb R^n}|f(x)|\,\mathrm d x\\
\leq&\,\int_A\,\mathrm d x+\int_{\mathbb R^n}|f(x)|\,\mathrm d x\\
=&\,m(A)+\int_{\mathbb R^n}|f(x)|\,\mathrm d x<\infty,
\end{align*}
given that $f\in L^1$.

Comment: why the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Let $B$ be any bounded set that contains the support of $f$. By [Jensen's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality),
$$
\frac1{|B|}\int_B|f(x)|^p\mathrm{d}x\le\left(\frac1{|B|}\int_B|f(x)|\mathrm{d}x\right)^{\large p}
$$
since $|x|^p$ is concave for $0\le p\le1$.

Answer (score 0):

They are quite different; the first I imagine you used that $|f|^p \leq |f| M^{1-p}$ where $M$ is the bound for $f$.

You'll want to bound the $L^1$ norm of $|f|^p$ by the $L^1$ norm of $f$ multiplied by something to do with the measure of it's support; the following inequality may come in useful: for $1\leq p,q\leq \infty$ with $1/p + 1/q=1$, $\int fg \leq (\int |f|^p)^{1/p}(\int |g|^q)^{1/q}$. (Notice if you choose $g$ to be the characteristic function of the support of $f$, the second term on the RHS will be the measure of the support of $f$ to a power)